# is it possible to optimise spreadsheetgear performance?

Tags: spreadsheetgear

I am using the spreadsheetgear library in a web application that manages some large spreadsheets, populating cell values and extracting the results. It runs extremely fast for small spreadsheets but we are noticing problems with more sophisticated ones. One possible improvement that springs to mind is that as we are setting each parameter cell value I imagine that the other cell values are being recalculated immediately (possibly?), so if I set a lot of cell values prior to extracting the results then those calculations are being run redundantly (num of parameters - 1) times. Of course I don't really know how it works, maybe it just calculates the relevant values when inspected... so can someone please let me know if that is the case and if so is there anything that can be done to delay processing?

Answer (score 0):

It looks like values are being calculated on pull from formula cell anyway.

Here is an explanation regarding some configuration settings
http://www.spreadsheetgear.com/support/help/spreadsheetgear.net.3.0/SpreadsheetGear~SpreadsheetGear.IWorkbookSet~CalculationOnDemand.html